# Show in notification bar when downloading to internal storage?

Tags: android, notifications, download

On Android, when you download files to the SD, a notifiation bar showing the progress can be seen at the top. Now, I must download a file to the **internal storage** of my phone - where it will be inaccessible to other apps.

**Q:** Is it possible to show such a notification where the user can stop the download? How?

What I'm trying to do here is to allow the user to do other stuff while downloading the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: You have to build the notification by yourself, see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for details.

Long: If I have understood it right then the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) would take care of putting a notification into the bar. But the interface looks somewhat limited as the documentation only talks about HTTP downloads and only seem to have options to set a path to external storage.

So if I'm correct you can't use the DownloadManager, so you don't get the notifications for free. You would have to impplement them by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was the case. Well, now we know for sure.